# Generating process in R

Tags: r, random-variable, random-generation

I have to generate 10000 steps of the following process:
Y(t) ~iid N(0,1)

X(0) = 0 
X(t+1) = X(t) + Y(t)

I also need to check percentage of negative results of X(t).

I am new to R and I have a problem with that excercise. Can you give me some tips? Do I have to use some kind of loop? And how to set X(0) to 0?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In R it is almost always more preferable to use vectorization instead of loops. For instance, in your case

```
n=10000
Y=rnorm(n)
X=cumsum(Y)
NC=sum(X<0) #count of negative values in X
```

Vectors are indexed by numbers $1,2,...$. No zero or negative indexes are allowed. So you cannot put X[0]=0. Formally speaking, this is a correct operator, but X[0] means the empty subvector of X, so nothing is changed.